# Need some clarification concerning given PHP code fragment

Tags: php

Came across the following PHP code fragment

```
class SearchGoogle extends Thread
{
    public function __construct($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->html = file_get_contents('http://google.fr?q='.$this->query);
    }
}

$searches = ['cats', 'dogs', 'birds'];
foreach ($searches as &$search) {
    $search = new SearchGoogle($search);
    $search->start();
}
```

I have a problem understanding the `foreach` loop below. To me it looks like
the `$search` variable is used simultaneously both as element of `$searches` array and as an instance of `SearchGoogle`. Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: Since it is used as a reference (`as &$search`, note the ampersand) that means the original entry in $searches (the string `'cats'` for example) gets overwritten with an instance of `SearchGoogle` relating to that search term. After the loop, `$searches` would look **like** `SearchGoogle('cats'), SearchGoogle('dogs'), SearchGoogle('birds')` instead of `'cats', 'dogs', 'birds'`.

Comment: Thanks for your simple and compact explanation. That was cool. How can I mark your post as the one which helped me?

Comment: It's a comment, you can't (except upvoting it). I should've posted it as an answer but didn't feel like it met my standards ;-) You can just accept the answer of @ÁlvaroGonzález since it has the same info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is loosely typed, nothing prevents you from reusing a variable:

```
$foo = 'Bar';
var_dump($foo);
$foo = M_PI;
var_dump($foo);
$foo = new DateTime();
var_dump($foo);
```

```
string(3) "Bar"
float(3.1415926535898)
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-05-31 12:29:01.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
}
```

In this case, though, the code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
$searches = ['cats', 'dogs', 'birds'];
foreach ($searches as $index => $search) {
    $searches[$index] = new SearchGoogle($search);
    $searches[$index]->start();
}
```

In other words, it replaces the strings in the array with instances of the `SearchGoogle` class.